# Get a summary count of a text format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of product ID's & names. Below is the question.

Is there any Product ID which represent more than one Product Name? If yes, list all Product IDs with Product Names.

What I have tried is;

```
df_productID=df[['Product ID','Product Name']]
df_productID.groupby(['Product ID','Product Name']).count().reset_index()
```

But I do not get a count. Just a list of product names & ID's.

Please help!

Comment: could it be `df_productID.groupby('Product ID')['Product Name'].value_counts()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
 df_productID.groupby('Product ID')['Product Name'].nunique()
```

which gives you the number of unique `Product Name` for a given `Product ID`. Then You can check that series for values `1`. But if you want the actual `Product Name` associated with `Product ID`, then `value_counts` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('product_id')['product_name'].count()
```

By grouping by `product_id`, and using `.count()` on the `product_name`, you'll see how many products exist for each product_id.

It's perhaps better to use:

```
df.groupby('product_id')['product_name'].nunique()
```

Because this will only consider unique product_names. If any `product_id` has more than 1 `product_name` associated with it, you'll see a `.nunique()` count greater than 1.

Does that make sense?

Comment: You should explain a little more your answer. It's hard to tell how and why your answer would work.

Comment: Yes, please explain why this would solve the problem?